# BigQuery CREATE TABLE with dynamic table name

Tags: google-bigquery, ddl

I want to use the CREATE TABLE clause but make the table name a variable. Is this possible?

```
DECLARE table_name STRING;
SET table_name = '`my_dataset.my_table`';
CREATE TABLE table_name AS (SELECT 1)
```